# autocomplete not working with add row javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to insert input box with id as tags. After insert, I need the auto complete to function. I tried many ways but the input with tags cannot auto complete.

my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addCF").click(function () {
        $("#customFields").append('<tr><td>1</td><td><input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" id="cariBrg" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text"></td><td><input   class="form-control" name="harga_satuan[]" id="input1" onkeyup="calc()" value="" type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control" id="input2" onkeyup="calc()" name="jumlah_beli[]"   type="text"></td><td><input class="form-control" name="sub_total[]" value="" id="output" type="text"></td><td><button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red;"></i></  button></td></tr>');
    });
    $("#customFields").on('click', '.remCF', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

autocomplete

```
$(function () {
    $("#cariBrg").autocomplete({
        source: "cari-barang.php",
        minLength: 2,
    });
});
```

my HTML

```
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" name="kode_barang[]" id="cariBrg" placeholder="Ketik Kode / Nama Barang" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" name="harga_satuan[]" id="input1" onkeyup="calc()" value="" type="text"></td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" id="input2" onkeyup="calc()" name="jumlah_beli[]" type="text"></td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" name="sub_total[]" value="" id="output" type="text"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times" style="color: red;"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class='alert alert-info TotalBayar'>
    <button id='addCF' class='btn btn-default pull-left'><i class='fa fa-plus fa-fw'></i>Baris Baru (F7)</button>
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

instead of...

```
$("#cariBrg").autocomplete({
    source: "cari-barang.php",
    minLength: 2,
});
```

try this:

```
$('body').find("#cariBrg").autocomplete({
    source: "cari-barang.php",
    minLength: 2,
});
```